# Error C2079 and Error C2440 when trying to incorporate a new type into an existing type

Tags: c++

I'm not exactly sure why I'm getting these errors, I thought it was because I needed a forward declaration, but the problem still persists.  I have no clue what is causing this.  I put comments where the offending lines are.  Looking for an explanation on why this is happening and a resolution. Thanks.

```
// Player.h

#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

#include "Weapon.h"
#include "Monster.h"
#include <string>

// Forward declaration
class Race;

class Player
{
public:
    Player();

/*  Return Type     Method Name */
    bool            IsDead();
    std::string     GetName();
    int             GetArmor();

    void            TakeDamage(int damage);
    void            CreateClass();
    bool            Attack(Monster& monster);
    void            LevelUp();
    void            Rest();
    void            ViewStats();
    void            Victory(int xp, Monster* monster);
    void            GameOver();
    void            DisplayHitPoints();
    void            SetRace();

private:
/*  Type                Name */
    std::string         m_Name;
    std::string         m_ClassName;
    int                 m_Accuracy;
    int                 m_HitPoints;
    int                 m_MaxHitPoints;
    int                 m_ExpPoints;
    int                 m_NextLevelExp;
    int                 m_Level;
    int                 m_Armor;
    int                 m_Gold;
    Weapon              m_Weapon;
    Race                m_Race;  // problem: error C2079 uses undefined class 'Race'

};

#endif // PLAYER_H
```

An offending method with a cannot convert from 'Race' to 'int' error

```
void Player::SetRace()    
{
        Race race;
        m_Race = race.SelectRace();  // problem: error C2440 cannot convert from 'Race' to int
}
```

Race class definition:

```
// Race.h

#ifndef RACE_H
#define RACE_H

#include <string>

class Race
{
public:
    Race();

/*  Return Type     Method Name*/
    Race            SelectRace();
protected:

    std::string GetName();

/*  Type            Name*/
    std::string     m_Name;
    int             m_Accuracy;
    int             m_HitPoints;

};

// ...below here implements multiple derived classes of type race

#endif // RACE_H
```

Comment: @IgorTandetnik He did, theyre in comments next to the offending lines.

Comment: You need to include race at the top of player.h

Comment: Is it necessary for the program to contain _all_ of these lines in order for the problem to occur? What happened when you removed some functions and members? To create a _minimal_ testcase?

Comment: @Borgleader: Please don't write answers as comments. Thank you.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'll keep doing so just because you asked me not to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as you've found, a forward declaration is insufficient here. That's because there is a member of type `Race` in `Player`.

Include the whole header at the top of player.h:

```
#include "Weapon.h"
#include "Monster.h"
#include "Race.h"
```

Then the definition of your `Race` class will be visible to the definition of `Player`.

Comment: Yep, this was it...oddly enough though what caused me to try using the forward declaration was because I originally had it like this and it threw an error complaining about the same thing, but I forgot the default constructor definition in the Race.cpp file.  Thanks a lot.